# Divshot Page Editor - No Navigator?

Tags: navigator, divshot

I'm checking out DivShot for the first time, and have fallen at the first hurdle.

On launching the app, I get the page editing screen, as expected, with the Inspector, Components and Page Options tabs on the right hand side of the screen.

But on the left hand side, there is no Navigator.  And I can find no reference to the Navigator anywhere on the screen (thinking it might be a collapsed area, or something).

Looking at the Intro video on the Divshot website, there do seem to be some minor differences (the lack of the Navigator notwithstanding), so I am wondering whether something has changed in the latest release...

In any case, I can see no way of add files/resources/folder structures other than new pages, because of the absence of the Navigator.

Can anyone shed any light?

Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the now legacy version of Divshot. We recently launched Divshot 1.0 with file support and a completely revamped project structure.

Legacy: http://app.divshot.com

New Divshot: http://builder.divshot.com

It's on a separate instance so beta users have time to export their pages and finish anything up in the old version before upgrading. Since we moved from generic folders and pages to actual files we're offering a manual upgrade.

If you'd like to update you can just go to https://api.divshot.com/upgrade and follow the instructions there. We're pushing a notice to the old version right away to eliminate any confusion. Sorry about that!